# Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Requests' and limit 'Requests per minute' of service 'mybusinessbusinessinformation.googleapis.com' for consumer

Tags: google-my-business-api, oauth2-playground

I'm trying to collect and update data using the Business Information API.
In order to get the API Calls to work, I'm only trying to get information from my business by using "Get-requests". However when calling several methods, I keep receiving the following errors:
"Quota exceeded for quota metric 'Requests' and limit 'Requests per minute' ".
Both in the Postman-calls or the OAuth 2.0 Playground (which in my eyes: should be a sandbox, ready for testing - very frustrating…).

When I look for my quota in the API settings: I'm not even able to change the requests per minute other than '0'. This makes it really hard to test/use the API.
I can't even find out which categories there are for a business location…

For your information: I've already asked for increase of the quota using the forms. But it seems google isn't really responsive in this matter.

Can this be solved?
The API shall be used to update a group of 50 (or more) locations, this instead of bulk-editing with a csv-file.

Any help would be welcome.

Thanks in advance,
Kind Regards,
Seppe

Answer (score 0):

If the quota approval form was ignored, you might still have a chance via the API support (https://support.google.com/business/contact/api_default).

They might be reluctant to grant you a quota if your maximum location count is this low though - the API is designed for larger use cases.

Answer (score 0):

Is it documented anywhere that it's meant for larger users? I got approved being very clear it was only for a handful of locations.

BUT even though I got approved and have access there are 3 specific quotas (all per-minute) that are set to zero, even though I have tonnes of allowance for all the non-per-minute quotas. Seems like a bug to me.

I can make 10000 "Update Location requests per day" but zero per minute.